# Framerate() doesn't seem to affect Movie - Processing

Tags: video, processing, frame-rate

This must be something really stupid - so sorry if that's the case :) - but I really have been stuck on the simple issue for a long time now and I can't seem to understand it. Can't find anything on the *processing.org* documentation or the forum.

So basically, all I am doing is loading a `.mp4 Movie`, setting the `framerate`, and setting it to `loop()`. Everything draws as it should but the only issue is that the `.framerate()` doesn't seem to affect the Movie itself. Here is my simplified code for understanding:

```
String urlCam1 = "Something.mp4";
Movie camera1;

Movie currentCam;    

boolean drawNextFrame = false;

void setup() {
    fullScreen();

    camera1 = new Movie(this, urlCam1);  
    camera1.frameRate(1);
    camera1.loop();

    background(0);
}

void draw() {
    if (drawNextFrame) {
        image(currentCam, 0, 0, 100, 100);
        drawNextFrame = false;
    }
}

void movieEvent(Movie m) {
    print("Video Read");
    m.read();
    drawNextFrame = true;
    currentCam = m;
}
```

You may wonder why I'm using such a weird structure (notably with the `currentCam`), that's because I am drawing multiple Movies at once. But I have tried the code with only one Movie (as the code represents)  but the issue still prevails.

Notice how the `camera1.framerate` is set to 1 fps. For some reason, this line seems to be ignored even though no errors are given. The `movieEvent()` isn't called one time per second, but much more, and therefore, the current frame of the video isn't drawn each second also, even though I have explicitly set the framerate of the Movie to 1fps...

Why is that? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance ! :)

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue. I'm not seeing anything wrong with the code. I found a hack to reproduce the desired outcome but no solution to the real issue. Let me know if you want the hack (i.e. if you only want the visual effect without the benefits of a lower framerate).

Comment: Thank you @laancelot for the comment. After trying for a long time I just settled on using speed() instead which had the results I wanted which were basically just having a slower framerate on the video. But if you weren't able to reproduce the issue, framerate() must work, so I must be doing something wrong here... Hmm.Thank you for letting me know about your hack, but speed() works as I want, though it's much less precise as it takes a multiplier of the speed and not the speed itself. But I'll manage, thank you :) Also, then do you know the difference between framerate() and speed()? Thanks!

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem. I even tried it with the example code the Processing foundation show to explain `framerate()`. There might be a problem with the function itself, or we may share a wrong setting.

Comment: `framerate` doesn't change the speed of the video, it only show less frames per seconds. A 10 seconds video at half speed will last 20 seconds. The same video at half framerate will still last 10 seconds.

Comment: Oh, thank you @laancelot ! I though both functions did essentially the same thing, but your explanation clarifies things. It's pretty logical when I think about it. I think what must have confused me is that the sketch framerate() function changes the speed of the sketch. But yeah, speed() was what I was looking for, but framerate() doesn't seem to work as you explained neither. Thank you again! If you want, you can post this comment as an answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your problem, but not to correct it. After trying very simplified code based on the example in the Processing documentation, I still couldn't make `frameRate()` work. I even tried different renderers with no discernable results.

You can still get a similar result with simple techniques. For once, you can count your frames to only update the movie once every couple frames:

```
Movie myMovie;
int frameCounter = 0;
int framerate = 30;
int movieFPS = 3;  // the movie will be updated only 3 times per second
int updateFrame = 1;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  frameRate(framerate);
  updateFrame = framerate / movieFPS;

  myMovie = new Movie(this, "SampleVideo_360x240_30mb.mp4");
  myMovie.loop();
}

void draw() {
  if (frameCounter++ % updateFrame == 0) {
    image(myMovie, 0, 0);
  }
}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

What's interesting here is that the sound won't be affected, as the movie is still read at the same speed, just not graphically displayed every frame.

If you're going for the "webcam" effect, you can randomize the frame count instead of having it update regularly:

```
Movie myMovie;
int frameCounter = 0;
int framerate = 30;
int minFramesBetweenUpdate = 10;
int maxFramesBetweenUpdate = 45;
int updateFrame = 1;

void setup() {
  size(200, 200);
  frameRate(framerate);

  myMovie = new Movie(this, "SampleVideo_360x240_30mb.mp4");
  myMovie.loop();
}

void draw() {
  if (frameCounter++ > updateFrame) {
    image(myMovie, 0, 0);
    updateFrame = frameCounter + (int)random(minFramesBetweenUpdate, maxFramesBetweenUpdate);
  }
}

// Called every time a new frame is available to read
void movieEvent(Movie m) {
  m.read();
}
```

The framerate technically doesn't change the speed at which the movie will be displayed, only the number of frames that will be seen in a certain amount of time. A 10 seconds video with different framerates will always play in 10 seconds.

If you want to change the speed at which the movie is displayed, you need to use something like `myMovie.speed(0.5);`. The speed at which the movie is played will change how long it takes to run it. If your movie has sound, playing it at more than 1.0 speed will "chipmunk" the sound, for an example.

Let me know if I can help with something. And have fun!